# How to break object by anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

Suppose I have a rectangle, which has 4 anchor points in it's angles.

[image]

How to break it into set of 4 sides in the same places?

Below I show them shifted outside:

[image]

Comment: You can select spans and then cut and paste infront and the selected spans are nolonger connected.

Comment: Yup.. like @joojaa .. I'd merely direct select two sides, cut, and then paste in front/back. 1 click-drag, and 2 keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: How to do that please?

Comment: Select the spans with direct selection tool and hit Ctrl + X(for cut) and the Paste(Ctrl + V  or  Ctrl + Shift + V for paste in place).

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to install any script cause Illustrator has the **Scissors Tool** that will do just that. You will find it under the **Erase Tool** (or simply press <kbd>C</kbd> ).

Just select it and click the square's anchor points:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a script that can figure it out.
You need to install it in illustrator ,
This script is named "Cut At Selected Anchors"

You may find it in
http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/20-free-and-useful-adobe-illustrator-scripts--vector-3849

Comment: There is no actual need to propose a script for something that Illustrator already has. It's counterproductive to install scripts for everything just cause you don't know a native way of doing it.